# Eigenvalue of $AB$ where $A,B$ have prescribed row sums

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices such that the sum of elements of each row of $A$ is $1$ and the sum of elements of each row of $B$ is $2$.
>
> Prove that one eigenvalue of $AB$ is $2$.

My try is that one eigenvalue of $A$ is $1$ since the sum of each row is $1$ and similarly eigenvalue of $B$ is $2$ but I can't prove that eigenvalue of $AB$ is $2$.

Comment: For $A$, sum of each row is $1$ is equivalent to the column vector of all $1$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $1$. Same argument show the same column vector is an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue $2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Prove that if $A$ and $B$ have a common eigenvector $v$, with associated eigenvalues $\lambda_A$ and $\lambda_B$, then $v$ is also an eigenvector of $AB$ with associated eigenvalue $\lambda_A\lambda_B$.

Comment: But how do you know that they have a common eigenvector?

Comment: @Joe How did you prove that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$? And how did you prove that $2$ is an eigenvalue of $B$?

Comment: Ah, I see now. But FYI, I’m not the OP.

Comment: @Joe Oh, I didn't notice that. Glad to help ;)